# Mathematica gives complex value for an integral of a positive function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried

```
Integrate[1/Abs[x - y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

The result was (Mathematica 11.2.0.0)

```
(* -I \[Pi] *)
```

Comment: Mathematica 11.0.1 returns `-I (-I + 3 \[Pi])` and version 11.3 returns complicated bogus after quite some time. Something is severely broken here.

Comment: If you split the range of integration and exclude `x==y` you get   `Integrate[1/Abs[x - y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x - eps}, 
 Assumptions -> 1 > eps > 0] (*-1 - Log[eps]*)`.  `eps->0` shows that the integral diverges! MMA obviously  evaluates complex branches ..

Comment: MMA 11.3: `Integrate[1/RealAbs[x - y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]` gives :`\[Infinity]` a correct answer.

Comment: And in MMA 11.2 if you do it this way: `Integrate[Integrate[1/Abs[x - y], {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}]` gives `I*(Pi + 2*I)`